# aor-simple-graphql-client : Error when loading data

Tags: graphql, admin-on-rest, apollo-server

I'm trying to use aor-simple-graphql-client with my apollo server. I have an array with few elements and admin on rest show only the last element many times. When I do the same request with graphiql I can see all elements.

Here is my repo : https://github.com/JeresB/cuistot-aor
Here a picture to explain the error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eevxo.png)

Comment: It's traditional to show some code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Minor grammar corrections.

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help you: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/FAQ.html#can-i-have-custom-identifiers-primary-keys-for-my-resources

i had the same problem, i'm using mongoose and i simply rename _id with id with https://github.com/tepio/mongoose-rename-id and now it seems to work fine

Hope it helps